# How to sum groupBy in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is a simple question about Eloquent , this eloquents returns correctly the user group by name

```
$pujas = Bid::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->usuarios()->subasta()->groupBy('id_user')->get();
```

I need to sum the value of the users import in the auction, the row is called 'importe', the result now with this eloquent is this :

[image]

**UPDATE QUESTION**

I managed to get the sum of the id_subasta , how could I pass two variable with return response()->json ?

```
$pujas = Puja::take(10)->usuarios()->subasta()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $result = DB::select('SELECT SUM(importe) FROM pujas WHERE id_subasta = 15');
        if(\Request::ajax()) { 
            return response()->json($pujas);
                  }else{
            $mensaje = "NO";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you must use the drilldown approach and use the sum function of the query builder.

```
$pujas = Bid::take(10)->usuarios()->subasta()->groupBy('id_user')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

and for sum values you can create a service or loop over the users and sum the "imports" or add a new accessor in you model (in order to add a virtual attribute ) for getting the sum for one user.

Comment: I tried to use this , by I have a double in a row and sum doesn't work with this,.

Comment: Eloquent returns a collection and
get() is used to return array,

but if you use sum() instead of get() it might works